# Hardware Recommendation - Consumer Grade Wireless Router that is capable of routing to two separate networks from a single connection

Tags: vpn, router, wifi

I need to purchase a wireless router for an end user which is capable of routing between the public internet and our internal intranet depending on the traffic request.

Basically, I need the router to route anything on our intranet over a VPN tunnel, such as an Outlook connection to our Exchange server, file shares, etc. Everything else however, would need to go out over the user's home ISP.

Can somebody please recommend a wireless router which is capable of doing this? I'll need some details on how to set it up as well but that is a question better left for another thread.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites because of their very limited lifespan. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I DEFINITELY recommend this router:

[http://www.amazon.com/RT-N16-Wireless-N-Maximum-Performance-single/dp/B00387G6R8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00387G6R8)

flashed with either DD-WRT firmware:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_RT-N16

or with Tomato firmware:

http://tomatousb.org/tut:installing-on-asus-rt-n16

Either way, the modified firmware on this router will enable you to create true VPN tunnels using this router. Most consumer-grade firmware will only allow you to setup a VPN Passthrough, leaving the responsibility of maintaining the tunnel on the client computer itself.

Some info on setting up a VPN on DD-WRT is here:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VPN

Let me know if this helps, and if you have any more questions!

Comment: Thanks for this John. I'm reading up on the unit now...I appreciate the quick and well written response.

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind the hardware recommendation is based on personal experience. I've deployed that particular unit in both home and SOHO environments, and given the rather large amount of RAM in the unit, it does really well at handling steady throughput.